# User's OAuth2 Token into RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

How to correctly get the users's session oauth2 token ?

I implemented an OAuth2 Authorization/Resource server using `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`.

I implemented a client app, that uses the authorization server to login the user and gets his access token. The login phase is working perfectly and so the retreive of the login data (*using the access token by the oauth2 filters*). The `Principal` in the client app requests correctly shows all authorities filled by the authorization server.

I'd like to use the client app as a proxy to send Rest Request using the given Access Token of the user that requested the call.

I already tried to use `@EnableOAuth2Client` but that does not work. The `OAuth2RestTemplate` is null when tried to be autowired.

I had to reimplement a request scoped bean of a `RestTemplate` which get the `tokenValue` from the `SecurityContext`. This works, but I do not find this clean. This behavior is quite common, so I should miss something.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application.name: client
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myclient:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

        provider:
          myclient:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8090/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:8090/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8090/me
            user-name-attribute: name
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().oauth2Login()
        .and().oauth2Client()
        ;
        // @formatter:on

    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Qualifier("oauth2RestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
                    throws IOException {

                Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

                if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated() && auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) auth).getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("details");
                    String tokenValue = (String) details.get("tokenValue");

                    if (tokenValue != null) {
                        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue);
                    }
                }

                return execution.execute(request, body);
            }
        });


        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**In WebController**

```java
    private @Autowired @Qualifier("oauth2RestTemplate") RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/remote")
    public Map<String, Object> remote() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> resp = oauth2RestTemplate.getForObject(URI.create("http://localhost:8090/api/test"), Map.class);

        return resp;
    }
```

It works, but I do not think I should configure the `RestTemplate` myself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to define `OAuth2RestTemplate`. However, this is a more clean implementation.

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate() {

    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(format("%s/oauth/token", authServerUrl));
    resourceDetails.setClientId("client_id");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("client_secret");
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    resourceDetails.setScope(asList("read", "write"));

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
}
```

In this case, your Resource server will communicate with the authorization server on your behalf using its own credentials.

Comment: As far as I understand this is not the desired behavior. In your example app will access remote resource using own credentials and as result on the side of remote resource there will be no information about the resource owner who originally accessed our application.
To be honest i have the same problem as @CreatixEA and unfortunately no answer yet...

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can create `@Bean` of scope request with user token and then just insert it as a parameter/header when using RestTemplate.